# Problema com JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Classes e persistence.xml abaixo. O problema é: entityManager is coming NULL.

```
 @ManagedBean(name="pessoaController")
    @SessionScoped
    public class PessoaController{
    private List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();

    public PessoaController() {
        new PessoaHome().findById(1);
    }

    public List<Pessoa> getPessoas(){
        return pessoas;
    }
    public void setPessoas(List<Pessoa> pessoas){
        this.pessoas = pessoas;
    }

}    


@Stateless
public class PessoaHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PessoaHome.class);

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void persist(Pessoa transientInstance) {
    log.debug("persisting Pessoa instance");
    try {
        entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
        log.debug("persist successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("persist failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public void remove(Pessoa persistentInstance) {
    log.debug("removing Pessoa instance");
    try {
        entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
        log.debug("remove successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("remove failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public Pessoa merge(Pessoa detachedInstance) {
    log.debug("merging Pessoa instance");
    try {
        Pessoa result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
        log.debug("merge successful");
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("merge failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public Pessoa findById(int id) {
    log.debug("getting Pessoa instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        Pessoa instance = entityManager.find(Pessoa.class, id);
        log.debug("get successful");
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}



<persistence-unit name="postgresDS" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/postgresDS</jta-data-source>     

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>      
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
    </properties> 

</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Poderia traduzir seu título e sua pergunta para Português?

Comment: Favor da próxima vez não postar em inglês.

Comment: Você está fazendo deploy em qual servidor de aplicação? Poste para nós o seu datasource (`postgresDS`). Uma coisa que percebi é que seu datasource possui o mesmo nome de sua PU.

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti também notei esse detalhe, mas não tenho certeza se o erro é esse. Felipe, você já tentou trocar o nome do sua PU para outra coisa?

Comment: Como o @RicardoGiaviti falou, qual é o seu servidor de aplicação? Outra coisa, você colocou a referência do DataSource no web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Adicione `unitName` na anotação `PersistenceContext`.

Ficando assim:

```
//...
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "postgresDS")
private EntityManager entityManager;
//...
```

Comment: Se o persistence.context tiver só uma declaração, por padrão, não é necessário adicionar o nome. Ele nem conseguiria chamar o projeto caso esse fosse o motivo.